# Getting NSWindow resizing right in an auto layout world

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, nswindow, nsscrollview

I'm having problem getting vertical window resizing working with an auto layout scroll view.

**What I Want**

I would like to replicate, as closely as possible, my app's current window resizing behaviour. The width of the window is flexible, but the height of the window should generally track the height of the contents. Specifically:

1. Normally, the window automatically resizes its height to exactly
   match its contents (with the exception of #2).
2. The user can choose to manually resize the window so it's smaller than its
   contents, in which case the imbedded scroll view will scroll the
   contents. Once made shorter, the window remains that height until manually
   resized or the contents becomes equal or smaller than the window again.
3. If the contents grows to the point that the bottom of the window
   bumps into the dock or screen bounds, the window's height is pinned
   to that height, just as if the user has resized it.

**What I've Got**

I created a window with a set of representative subviews that mimic the basic needs of my app. The window's hierarchy is simple:

```
Window
    NSView (contentView)
        NSScrollView
            NSClipView (NSScrollView.contentView)
                NSView (NSScrollView.documentView)
                    A bunch of standard and custom subviews with constraints
```

You can download the test project here (macOS 10.12/Xcode 8): http://mbx.cm/t/4FUGY

I've organized the various subviews so they have a flexible width, but the constraints define exactly one possible height. The parent scroll view fills the content view of the window.

The auto layout stuff works great. The window automatically resizes to match the size of the contents. If the height of the contents changes, the height of the window changes to match. Awesome.

**What I Can't Get to Work**

I have had no luck getting NSWindow to let me manually resize its height. The resize indicator (when hovering over the edge) shows that I can alter the window's width, but not its height.

I initially thought "Oh, that's got to be a compression resistance priority in one of the scroll views." But I can find no combination of compression resistance or hugging priorities that will alter this behavior. I've tried setting the priorities of the scroll view itself, and on the documentView (which makes no sense to me, but I tried anyway). I tried the values 749, 499, 49, and 1 in every combination I could think of.

I've searched for every problem that seemed released to this, but most of the posted questions seemed to be addressing different problems.

I added a "Dump" button to log the vertical constraints. Everything listed appears to be as expected, except for a handful of NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint objects that I don't understand. However, these appear to be constraints between the document view and the clip view, so I assume those are automatically created and aren't part of the problem.

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082580 PartBoxView:0x608000140840'Part B'.height == 96   (active)>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000083de0 V:[PartBoxView:0x608000140840'Part B']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':NSView:0x6080001212c0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000083e80 V:[PartBoxView:0x608000140370'Part A']-(NSSpace(8))-[PartBoxView:0x608000140840'Part B']   (active)>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000082da0 V:|-(0)-[NSScrollView:0x6080001c10e0]   (active, names: '|':NSView:0x608000121400 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000083430 V:|-(0)-[NSView:0x6080001212c0]   (active, names: '|':NSClipView:0x10040e2a0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000081e00 V:[NSScrollView:0x6080001c10e0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':NSView:0x608000121400 )>
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x650000082b20 h=-&- v=-&- NSView:0x608000121400.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x102504ea0'Window' )>
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6500000823f0 h=-&- v=-&- NSClipView:0x10040e2a0.minY == 1   (active, names: '|':NSScrollView:0x6080001c10e0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000083480 V:[NSView:0x6080001212c0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':NSClipView:0x10040e2a0 )>
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x650000082440 h=-&- v=-&- V:[NSClipView:0x10040e2a0]-(1)-|   (active, names: '|':NSScrollView:0x6080001c10e0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000083d40 V:|-(0)-[PartBoxView:0x608000140370'Part A']   (active, names: '|':NSView:0x6080001212c0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000083c50 V:[NSImageView:0x608000161bc0]-(20)-|   (active, names: '|':PartBoxView:0x608000140370'Part A' )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000083bb0 V:|-(20)-[NSImageView:0x608000161bc0]   (active, names: '|':PartBoxView:0x608000140370'Part A' )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000083660 NSImageView:0x608000161bc0.height == 64   (active)>
```

I'm hoping someone with auto layout experience can tell me how to get #2 working. I'm pretty sure #3 will require some custom code, but #2 is the big hurdle.

**The Background**

I'm in the process of giving my app a major facelift. It's a pretty big app, so I started by creating a set of test projects to test out some of the new UI and techniques.

The first big undertaking is converting everything to auto layout. Most of it looks like it will be fairly smooth, and I'm looking forward to some of the many benefits of auto layout.

Answer (score 2):

There's no completely automated way to achieve your goal #2. You want two different modes. In one mode, the window is always made large enough to accommodate the content. If it grows, the window grows; if it shrinks the window shrinks. In the other mode, the window is allowed to be smaller than required to fit the content because the user resized it that way. In that case, if the content grows, the window doesn't grow; if it shrinks, the window doesn't shrink unless the content gets small enough that it all fits and then it switches back to the first mode.

Auto layout doesn't really do modes like this, at least not automatically. You will have to detect the mode changes and programmatically modify the constraints to implement the two behavior modes.

You have apparently created constraints between the document view and the clip view to keep their tops and bottoms coincident. That essentially forces the clip view and then the scroll view to be as large as the document view. The scroll view will never scroll because it will never be too small to show all of the content.

I think you may want two constraints for the bottom spacing. One constraint will be an inequality at required (1000) priority. You want to express that the clip view should never be bigger than the document view. The document view's bottom can be greater than or equal to the clip view's bottom, but never less than.

The second bottom spacing constraint will be an equality (with 0 constant, as now) but with priority slightly less than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut` (500). This expresses that you want the clip view and scroll view to be large enough to fit the content, unless that would force the window to grow or prevent the user from shrinking it.

The problem is that if the window is large enough to fit the content and then the content grows, that won't force the window to grow. What I've described implements the second mode.

You could try to implement the first mode by setting the second constraint's priority higher. The problem then is that the user won't be allowed to resize the window. You're back to your current situation.

What I think you'll need to do is notice when the content resizes, by observing the document view's `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification`. Be sure to tell the view to post that by setting its `postsFrameChangedNotifications` property to true. When the frame changes, if you think you should be in the first mode, set the second constraint's priority higher, call `-layoutIfNeeded` on the window, and then set the priority back down. I think you may need to defer setting the priority down to the next turn of the event loop because it's not clear that you'll get the notification after the clip view has, so maybe use GCD to schedule that.

So, how do you know which mode you should be in? I'm not entirely sure. I *think* it will work for the window delegate (often its controller) to implement `-windowDidEndLiveResize:` to know when the user has finished resizing the window. I think the user resizing it will be a live resize while programmatically resizing it or auto layout resizing it won't be.

If it was the user who resized the window, you then need to know if the user grew the window so all of the content fits or if the user sized it smaller than that. For that, you could compare the height of the document view's bounds against the clip view's `documentVisibleRect`.

Comment: Ken,

Thanks for the thorough and thoughtful response.

Answer (score 1):

Ken,

Thanks for the thorough and thoughtful response.

> You have apparently created constraints between the document view and the clip view to keep their tops and bottoms coincident.

Well, I didn't, but IB certainly did. ;)

So the first step was to edit the clip view constraints, changing the clipView.bottom-0-documentView.bottom constraint from "equals 0" to "less than or equal to 0". That permits the clip view to be (vertically) smaller than the document view, ultimately allowing the user to resize the window vertically.

I then started with your other suggestions, adding some additional constraints to pin the height to the document and either modifying its `active` property or changing its `priority`.

Ultimately, however, I went a slightly different route. The problem is that when you ask the window's contents to grow a lot, or when it's close to the bottom of the screen, its behavior is ... well, weird.

Instead, I created a "sticky" mode for the window. When set, and the document view grows, I manually calculate a new frame for the window. I do this because I can control how the window resizes when it is near the bottom, and/or top, of the screen.

**Warning**

I discovered the hard way that there's a hidden danger to all of these techniques. The `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification` is sent whenever the frame is resized. This can happen *during* auto layout. If you observe this notification and immediately adjust the window size, content size, or constraints, auto layout gets very upset and throws nasty "circular" and "recursive" layout warnings (it also sometimes fails to resize properly). The solution was to simply wrap up the window size fix in a block and queue it to execute on the main thread, after all of the auto layout logic has finished.

Here's the finished, working, test project (with comments and notes): http://mbx.cm/t/Zjdml

Here's the relevant code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
  BOOL windowSizeSticky;      // a change in the content size should resize the window to match
}

- (void)documentSizeChangedNotification:(NSNotification*)notification;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
  self.view.window.delegate = nil;
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Enable the document view to post size change notifications
  NSView* docView = self.scrollView.documentView;
  docView.postsFrameChangedNotifications = YES;
  // Subscribe to those changes
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(documentSizeChangedNotification:)
                         name:NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification
                         object:docView];
  // Queue up an initial evaluation so windowSizeSticky is set correctly
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self documentSizeChangedNotification:nil];
    });
}

- (void)viewWillAppear
{
  // Make this controller the window's delegate
  self.view.window.delegate = self;

  [super viewWillAppear];
}

- (void)windowDidEndLiveResize:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  // Whenever the user resizes the window, reevaluate the windowSizeSticky mode
  NSView* documentView = self.scrollView.documentView;
  NSClipView* clipView = (NSClipView*)(documentView.superview);
  NSRect docVisible = clipView.documentVisibleRect;
  NSRect docFrame = documentView.frame;

  // Update the "sticky" mode depending on whether the window now displays all, or only a portion, of the contents
  windowSizeSticky = (docVisible.size.height==docFrame.size.height);
}

- (void)documentSizeChangedNotification:(__unused NSNotification *)notification
{
  NSView* documentView = self.scrollView.documentView;
  NSWindow* window = documentView.window;
  if (!window.inLiveResize)   // Suppress this logic while the user is manually resizing the window
    {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      // Do this the next time the main loop is idle
      // This notification can be sent during auto layout, and we don't want to attempt to resize
      //  the window in the middle of an auto layout calculation.

      // The geometry of the document view has changed; check to see if the window needs resizing
      NSClipView* clipView = (NSClipView*)(documentView.superview);
      NSRect docVisible = clipView.documentVisibleRect;
      NSRect docFrame = documentView.frame;   // The doc's frame is in the clip view's coordinate system
      if (docVisible.size.height==docFrame.size.height)
        {
        // All of the document is (vertically) visible in the clip view
        // That means the window is displaying all of its contents
        // Whenever this happens, switch to "sticky" mode so future changes in content will make the window grow
        windowSizeSticky = YES;
        }
      else if (windowSizeSticky && docVisible.size.height < docFrame.size.height)
        {
        // The content is now taller than the view port of the scroll view & the window is "sticky"
        // Try to make the window taller so all of the content is exposed
        NSRect windowFrame = window.frame;
        CGFloat addHeight = docFrame.size.height-docVisible.size.height;

        NSRect contentRect = [window contentRectForFrameRect:windowFrame];
        contentRect.size.height += addHeight;

        // Calculate an ideal window frame, then adjust the existing frame so it's as close as we can get
        NSRect targetFrame = [window frameRectForContentRect:contentRect];
        CGFloat deltaY = targetFrame.size.height-windowFrame.size.height;
        if (deltaY >= 1.0)
          {
          // The window needs to be taller
          // Make it tall enough to display all of the content, keeping its title bar where it is
          windowFrame.origin.y -= deltaY;
          windowFrame.size.height += deltaY;

          // Screen bounds check...
          NSRect visibleFrame = window.screen.visibleFrame;
          if (visibleFrame.origin.y>windowFrame.origin.y)
            {
            // The bottom of the window is now below the visible area of the screen
            // Move the whole window up so it's back on the screen
            windowFrame.origin.y = visibleFrame.origin.y;
            if (visibleFrame.origin.y+visibleFrame.size.height < windowFrame.origin.y+windowFrame.size.height)
              {
              // The top of the window is now off the top of the screen
              // Shorten the window so it's entirely within the screen
              windowFrame.size.height = visibleFrame.size.height;
              // This also means "sticky" mode is off, since we had to size the window to something smaller
              //  than its contents.
              windowSizeSticky = NO;
              }
            }
          [window setFrame:windowFrame
               display:NO
               animate:NO/* be consistent; constraints doesn't animate when getting shorter */];
          }
        }
      // else { window is not sticky OR its contents doesn't exceed the height of the window: do nothing }
      });
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: For the record, when I went to fold this into my project it ultimately made more sense to implement this logic on the window controller, rather than the view controller.

Comment: This answer works for me, I have to change outline cell size according to outline view size, which changed when window resized.
WindowDidResize and WindowDidEndLiveresize event works but sometimes fail to respond last size result. But this works good.
Thanks