# Make `NSScrollView` large enough to fit document view but not so large it will make the window overflow the screen

Tags: swift, cocoa, autolayout

## Problem

This is an issue I'm having with an open source Cocoa framework I'm developing, [EasyDialogs](https://github.com/marcoconti83/EasyDialogs).

The goal is to programmatically display a form (a bunch of controls) inside a window, and automatically resize the window to a "sensible" size that is never larger than the screen.

However when opening a form window ([`FormWindow`](https://github.com/marcoconti83/EasyDialogs/blob/master/EasyDialogs/window/FormWindow.swift)), the window has a size that does not match the size of the controls in the form and needs to be manually resized by the user.

## Expected behaviour

The desired behaviour of the window ([`FormWindow`](https://github.com/marcoconti83/EasyDialogs/blob/master/EasyDialogs/window/FormWindow.swift)) is that the window expands to a size that is large enough to include the form controls (minimum size necessary to display all controls), **unless** that would make the window larger than the screen. In this case, the window should be limited by the screen size, and the form controls will be clipped (inside a scroll view).

## How to reproduce

1. check out the [fix/form-window-resizing](https://github.com/marcoconti83/EasyDialogs/tree/fix/form-window-resizing) branch
2. run `carthage bootstrap --platform osx`
3. open XCode and run the `EasyDialogExample` schema
4. The app will open an show a window with a button for "Large" or "Small" form. Try both.

## Details

The window in [`FormWindow`](https://github.com/marcoconti83/EasyDialogs/blob/master/EasyDialogs/window/FormWindow.swift) is composed of three sections:

- [header](https://github.com/marcoconti83/EasyDialogs/blob/master/EasyDialogs/window/FormWindow.swift#L157), it's just a label
- [stack of controls](https://github.com/marcoconti83/EasyDialogs/blob/master/EasyDialogs/window/FormWindow.swift#L159), the actual form controls
- [footer](https://github.com/marcoconti83/EasyDialogs/blob/master/EasyDialogs/window/FormWindow.swift#L158), it's the "OK"/"Cancel" buttons

The three sections are [constrained](https://github.com/marcoconti83/EasyDialogs/blob/master/EasyDialogs/window/FormWindow.swift#L163) to be on top of each other, in that order, filling the entire window. The relevant part for the purpose of this issue is the stack.

The stack is a `NSStackView` inside a `NSScrollView`. The `NSStackView` holds the form controls. The desired behavior is that the scroll view will grow to adjust to the minimum size necessary to accommodate the stack with no clipping, unless this will make the whole window larger than the screen, i.e. the top (or bottom) of the window is far off the screen and it can not be reached with the mouse.

If this were to happen, the `NSScrollView` should instead clip the stack view, so that the window is as large as the screen but it does not grow beyond it, and the user can scroll to visit the entire stack.

### Attempted solution

#### Set the scroll size min and max

`scroll.height <= stack.height
scroll.height >= 300`

Why it doesn't work: the scroll size is always the minimum one. I need to manually resize the window after it's displayed.

#### Set the scroll size to be the stack size

`scroll.height == stack.height`

Why it doesn't work: the window is always as large as needed to display the form. This works as long as the stack plus the rest of the window is smaller than the screen. However it will make the window larger than the screen.

#### Modify the scroll view `intrinsicContentSize`

I subclassed `NSStackView` to return an intrinsic content size which is equal to the size of the `documentView`. However, the intrinsic size property is accessed before performing the layout, so the intrinsic content size of the subview at that moment is `(-1,-1)`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to first setup the scroll view content and the window such that their sizes nicely fit the content (i.e. ignoring the problem with the screen size) and then in a second step constrain the window frame into the rectangle returned by `NSScreen`'s `visibleFrame` method?

Comment: I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229402/getting-nswindow-resizing-right-in-an-auto-layout-world), actually bit more complicated than this. I think the basic trick is to get your layout constraints so they hug/compress the window height with a priority > 500 (the window resizing priority), but less than 1000; the window should naturally keep from resizing itself beyond the usable screen rect. If that doesn't do it, look at what I finally did.